# Определение вероятности показа

Tags: алгоритм, php

К примеру есть 5 ссылок, у каждой ссылки есть приоритет:

```
№ ссылки/приоритет
1 / 1
2 / 1
3 / 4
4 / 2
5 / 1
```

как можно рассчитать так, чтобы каждая ссылка показывалась N количество раз но, чем выше приоритет, тем выше вероятность показа ссылки?

Answer (score 2):

```
$link_to_show = -1;//Че показывать будем?
$last_probability = 1001;//Заведомо большее число, чем возможно 
for($i=0;$i<$N;$i++){// бегаем по ссылкам
  $current_probability = rand(0,ceil(1000/$priority));// получившееся рэндомное число не больше, чем 1000/приоритет. Соответственно, чем выше приоритет, тем меньше число.
  if($current_probability<$last_probability){// сравниваем
    $link_to_show = $i;// если эта ссылка круче, меняем на нее
    $last_probability = $current_probability;
  }
}

show_link($link_to_show);
```

Ну, типа того.

Answer (score 1):

Сделай что-то типа генератор ссылок, который будет генерировать очередную ссылку согласно некоторому распределению, которые построишь по твоим приоритетам. 
распределение такое:  
№ссылки - вероятность  
1 - 1/9 
2 - 1/9 
3 - 4/9 
4 - 2/9 
5 - 1/9